# vb.net - grabbing the value ot a text input box displayed in a webview and bringing it back into winforms

Tags: html, vb.net, webview, visual-studio-2017, webbrowser-control

I've got a winform that contains a webview.
At some points the webview will display html content including input boxes for the end user to throw some responses into.

Is it possible for me to interact with the input box in the webview to grab its contents programatically?
Even if its just to display that text in a messagebox as an example, that will get me well on my way!

so in the example form below, I'd be looking to grab whatever the end user entered into 'userresponse' and throw it into a variable. like...

```
 dim response as string = 'the contents of the input box in the webview
 messagebox.show(response)
```

any help appreciated and thanks in advance! :)

```
 <HTML>
     <Body>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="userresponse" name="userresponse"><br>
      </form>
     </Body>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: How about the issue, is there anything to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [InvokeScriptAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop.webviewcontrol.invokescriptasync?view=winrt-19041) to to achieve it.

Sample code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim html As String = File.ReadAllText("test1.html")
    WebView1.NavigateToString(html)
End Sub

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ss As String = Await WebView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", New String() {"document.getElementById('userresponse').value;"})
    MsgBox(ss)
End Sub

End Class
```

Result:

[image]